# How to use format function in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am trying to register an application in Azure AD using TF and i would like to define some redirect URIs using the arg as mentioned in the link --> https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application :

```
reply_urls                 = ["https://replyurl"]
```

But i have to put 3 URIs and the format of the URI is like this below :

```
https://(project code)-yellow-(resourcegroup).azurewebsites.net/oauth2-redirect.html
https://(project code)-blue-(resourcegroup).azurewebsites.net/oauth2-redirect.html
https://(project code)-green-(resourcegroup).azurewebsites.net/oauth2-redirect.html
```

So the second part is changing only and the other part is constant. We cannot hardcode URIs for best practices
Also, we need to use format function
So can anyone tell how to put the reply_urls using the format function so that only the middle part changes as described above
Also, can this be done in any way using concat for that matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `project_id` and `resourcegroup` as input parameters to your TF code:

```
variable "project_id" {}
variable "resource_group" {}
```

Then your `reply_urls` could be:

```
reply_urls  = [
       format("https://%s-yellow-%s.azurewebsites.net/oauth2-redirect.html", var.project_id, var.resource_group),
       format("https://%s-blue-%s.azurewebsites.net/oauth2-redirect.html", var.project_id, var.resource_group),
       format("https://%s-green-%s.azurewebsites.net/oauth2-redirect.html", var.project_id, var.resource_group)  
]
```

Comment: The problem is in our internal TF Best Practices confluence page, it is written "Do Not Use Interpolation Syntax". Recommended to use Format Function. That's where the challenge is here, otherwise i could have done it with interpolation syntax which is much easier to do . Is interpolation not a good practice you think?

Comment: @Pallab I updated the answer with format. I don't know why would interpolation was bad.

Comment: Possibly the concern with interpolation is that the variable name is embedded inside a literal string. This means the reference to a variable is hidden one layer down and requires an extra level of parsing to retrieve it. I'm not familiar with Terraform but possibly some tools won't be able to find this reference and literal strings can't be treated as pure literals anymore, because they may contain variables. I don't really like interpolation in other languages if a template approach is available instead.